# React not responding to (redux) state change?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

For some reason react is not re-rendering when the (redux) state changed. Might it be because it is nested 1 level? Also in the redux inspector I can see that the state has changed correctly and as expected. On manually refreshing the page, I can also see that it worked. But I am confused on why it is not re-rendering automatically.

**Simplified Class Component**

```
class Users extends Component {
    render() {
        const something = this.props.users.users;

        return (
            <div>
                <div className='MAIN_SECTION'>
                    <SearchBar handleChange={(value) => this.setState({searchQuery: value})} />

                    <div className='LIST'>
                        {something.mapObject((user) => <div onClick={() => this.props.deleteUser(user.id)}>{user.name}</div>)}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        users: state.users
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { deleteUser })(Users);
```

**Action Creator**

```
export function deleteUser(userhash) {
    return function (dispatch, getState) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)).then(() => {
            const data = {
                status: 200,
                data: {
                    status: 200
                }
            };

            if (data.status === 200) {
                const newState = getState().users.users;
                delete newState[userhash];

                dispatch({
                    type: DELETE_USER,
                    payload: {
                        data: newState
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    };
}
```

**Reducer**

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    isFetching: true,
    users: {}
};

case DELETE_USER:
    return {
        ...state,
        users: action.payload.data
    };
```

Comment: Since you are using Promise in your action you have to use thunk-middleware. Are you using it?

Comment: @bartekfr Yes I am, everything is working as expected with the promise (as I can use .then() etc), state is changing as expected. Only react does not re-render.

Answer (score 0):

Once you dispatch action DELETE_USER,

```
const something = this.props.users.users;
```

doesn't look right.

You are doing this in action which means something must be this.props.user.

```
            const newState = getState().users.users;
            delete newState[userhash];

            dispatch({
                type: DELETE_USER,
                payload: {
                    data: newState
                }
            });
```

In your render, this.props.users itself is the array of users.

To have a dirty fix, changing mapStateToProps to:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    users: state.users.users || state.users
  };
}
```

Change in render:

```
const something = this.props.users;
```

Comment: If his reducer is named `users` everything is fine. At any rate, it doesn't matter what he writes in the constructor, as long as the props mapping is OK. Besides, if that weren't correct, initial users rendering wouldn't have worked.

Comment: @OmriAharon so can it be that react doesn't see the nested change in props?

Comment: @NealVDV Could be, hard to say.. you can place a breakpoint/console.log and check it.

Comment: @OmriAharon where would I put this `console.log()`?

Comment: `function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log(state.users);
    return {
        users: state.users
    };
}`

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't really jive to me. In one spot you are you are using `.map()` on `users.users` and in another spot you are using `delete[newHash]` on it. So is it an array, or an object?

But hypothetically, let's say it did work. You say that that the state has changed correctly.

Let's assume the initial state is

```
{
    isFetching: true,
    users: { users: ['12345', '67890'] }
}
```

Let say user '12345' gets deleted, in the action, we have these sequence of events

```
const newState = getState().users.users; // ['12345', '67890']
delete newState[userhash]; // ['67890'] if you use your imagination

dispatch({
     type: DELETE_USER,
     payload: {
         data: newState // ['67890']
})
```

Finally, in the reducer

```
case DELETE_USER:
return {
    ...state,
    users: action.payload.data // ['67890']
};
```

So the final state is

```
{
    isFetching: true,
    users: ['67890']
}
```

It's not the same shape as the original state - users no longer has a users.users.

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistake, it is originally an object but i'm using a self created "mapObject" function which has the same behavior as an `array.map()` but then for an object. So for simplicity sake I changed it to a `.map()`.